# MSVC: Length of String Literal appears wrong in constexpr context

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working on a custom string_view type (for fun, I'm aware of std::string_view).
I'd like to be able to generate constexpr string views from string literals.

However, my current code for this gives wrong results when compiled with msvc in debug mode, as illustrated by the following sample program:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct strview
{
    const char* m_beg;

    const char* m_end;

    size_t m_bytes;

    template<size_t Bytes>
    static constexpr strview from_literal(const char (&lit)[Bytes]) noexcept
    {
        return { lit, lit + Bytes - 1, Bytes - 1 };
    }

    constexpr size_t len() const noexcept
    {
        return m_end - m_beg;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr strview constexpr_sv = strview::from_literal("???");

    // How does this pass?
    static_assert(constexpr_sv.len() == constexpr_sv.m_bytes);

    // constexpr: length = 7, bytes = 3
    printf("constexpr: length = %zd, bytes = %zd\n", constexpr_sv.len(), constexpr_sv.m_bytes);

    const strview const_sv = strview::from_literal("???");

    // runtime: length = 3, bytes = 3
    printf("runtime: length = %zd, bytes = %zd\n", const_sv.len(), const_sv.m_bytes);
}
```

This appears to work fine when compiled with [gcc](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmpAAOqAqETgwe3r56icmOAkEh4SxRMXF2mA6pQgRMxATpPn5ctpj2uQxVNQT5YZHRsbbVtfWZTQqDXcE9RX1mAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMwcjeWADUJutuyGP4qAfYJhoAgpdXY8ReDrv3AG54mADutyYA7FbXlwAnGgGGNdsgEDUAFS7FgAfSiwAO/xuAI0wIEYIh0NhcNcyO%2BaMByQAXpg4QRcREAJ4ETAKAlo1GAukseIGOkHNyk8mUiy0%2BnnQnE6qOZDgzF01TxYjPAjEN6fXZUYioeG0QjRMQQEFYyGyiDmABsGoIsxMAFYLPy6QyLQARWa7BioTCqFbxAjC34ooFA4iYAhLBj7P67U2kcOEfaWXY2%2Bm7AC0uyacYFCiTKdD9sZzN%2BOaZQN1UplzzwZIp4cYECdxedrvdmE93r%2B3vRAaDxBD8NcmfhiNzfp%2BBZuw8H12ClJYTGCNe%2BraJxbdpde7w%2BEtBJeIcIUL3263tcoVa5AIBVarhpq1tENZjMBwAYo/n3fzetfUSAPSf3YACVQ67oK6GYEAgeAZvETAKAy6xPkSYxMGKcJQUotQ6pKy7bruAB09AMDW%2B45geG5jJhO4vNh/bpm%2BH7MjKk5ULeZhLtKMRVkYoGETGFokugkY0raXHmDx6CWm4DDmHEJFbuRuHVvM0lkThVG2jRhLMnWq5KsW5FcVpHynue6qasQ2qSc%2BsEvnM450cQDFMQ8gh4GwIDscAnEHIewm8fx6ZCWYIliRJd6RjpOF4TWoWSrJKn0mpAJjtcHDzLQnAWrwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYzyLMsmAxusPCkAQmjJfMADWIDrEa2GAlwFoABwaBaXBGl1PwdUa%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%2BsVc1w8MtegsoNhNxbrNDuZh/7lSNBoDQd5JDrB7j8AKY8J5T11uNWwc9W41THmYLO09sF4PbqQfWyRnCSCAA%3D%3D) and [clang](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmpAAOqAqETgwe3r56icmOAkEh4SxRMXF2mA6pQgRMxATpPn5ctpj2uQxVNQT5YZHRsbbVtfWZTQqDXcE9RX1mAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMwcjeWADUJutuyGP4qAfYJhoAgpdXY8ReDrv3AG54mADutyYA7FbXlwAnGgGGNdsgEDUAFS7FgAfSiwAO/xuAI0wIEYIh0NhcNcyO%2BaMByQAXpg4QRcREAJ4ETAKAlo1GAukseIGOkHNyk8mUiy0%2BnnQnE6qOZDgzF01TxYjPAjEN6fXZUYioeG0QjRMQQEFYyGyiDmABsGoIsxMAFYLPy6QyLQARWa7BioTCqFbxAjC34ooFA4iYAhLBj7P67U2kcOEfaWXY2%2Bm7AC0uyacYFCiTKdD9sZzN%2BOaZQN1UplzzwZIp4cYECdxedrvdmE93r%2B3vRAaDxBD8NcmfhiNzfp%2BBZuw8H12ClJYTGCNe%2BraJxbdpde7w%2BEtBJeIcIUL3263tcoVa5AIBVarhpq1tENZjMBwAYo/n3fzetfUSAPSf3YACVQ67oK6GYEAgeAZvETAKAy6xPkSYxMGKcJQUotQ6pKy7bruAB09AMDW%2B45geG5jJhO4vNh/bpm%2BH7MjKk5ULeZhLtKMRVkYoGETGFokugkY0raXHmDx6CWm4DDmHEJFbuRuHVvM0lkThVG2jRhLMnWq5KsW5FcVpHynue6qasQ2qSc%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%2B3laQ7/RKErCrAhmqLaH9LpUxfh8JevBd5XGILzCaDtVDlCqPgTKvARbCFEOISWGCZZqDGgrfQe0VaWGsOrTW8AdZ60xAgjOSws6x1QY/c%2Bl9IE/VIB8Uy8ROZDQ4OlReY0C7YCQXvIgspi6l3LrsYAyBxRcHWNhLgjd8qkLVrsZuYi24d3Xt3Xu6wFH6MMUY4xvCF5QPGhwVeM0u41V4WYPOy8EE2J7qQY2yRnCSCAA%3D%3D%3D).

Everything also works for x64 msvc (version 19.29.30137) with /O2. However when compiling in debug mode the output is unexpected (compiler explorer sadly does not support output for msvc, so this is pasted from my machine):

constexpr: **length = 7, bytes = 3**
runtime: length = 3, bytes = 3

Note that the static_assert checking that len() and m_bytes are equal passes, but the output nonetheless shows that len() returns 7, while m_bytes is 3 (which are NOT equal), and everything also works as expected when using the from_literal function as non-constexpr.

I assume this code is running into undefined behaviour, but I'm not a language lawyer and haven't been able to figure out how exactly I'm running afoul of the standard. I'd appreciate any pointers as to what exactly I'm doing wrong and - ideally - how to fix it.

Comment: Works with ver 19.29.30151 (the oldest I have)

Comment: Wait - it fails in 32-bit mode (you forgot to specify that detail :-) with VS2019, but works with VS2022. So possibly a bug that has been fixed in later versions.

Comment: Btw: You may want to use a user defined literal for this purpose, similar to [`operator ""sv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv). Furthermore I'm not a huge fan of storing the same info twice in a class, since that makes it harder to maintain: begin and end iterators basically provide the same information as begin + size, so either the end iterator or the size should go...

Comment: @BoP I am encountering the problem in 64-bit mode. Thank you for noticing that I didn't mention it, I clarified my question now.

Comment: @fabian Thank you, I'll look into that! The duplication is just to make the Bytes template parameter accessible for printf and showing that it actually disagrees with (m_end - m_beg) :)

Comment: @fabian I just tried implementing a custom operator ""_sv, but it has the exact same problem. Given this and BoP's comment I'm almost tempted to assume that this is actually a compiler bug... Guess I'll just have to upgrade, which wouldn't hurt anyways :)

Comment: This compiles with MSVC 19.31 and more recent. Looks like a fixed compiler bug, see https://godbolt.org/z/13qh4Pf4T

Comment: @JanSchultke, in online compiler it passes even with `x64 msvc version 19.29`: https://godbolt.org/z/xz7TrKj58 But as OP mentions *compiler explorer sadly does not support output for msvc,*